# I want to print a sorted array in C using count sort but my code is not working

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, sorting, malloc

[image]I want to print a sorted array in C using count sort but my code is not working !
I watched a tutorial of the countsort algorithm and copied the code from the video but for some reason my code is not working while the code runs in the video .
I also wrote comments based on the work that the part of the code is doing in this script.
The output should be the given array and a sorted array on next line

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<limits.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void displayArray(int *arr,int size){
    printf("[ ");
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }
    printf("]\n");
}

int maximum(int A[], int size){
    int max = INT_MIN;
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        if(max < A[i]){
            max = A[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}

void countSort(int* A, int size){
    int i,j;

    // Find the maximum element in Array
    int max = maximum(A,size);

    // Create the count array
    int* count = (int*) malloc((max+1)*sizeof(int));

    // Initialize the count array elements to zero
    for(i=0; i < size+1; i++){
        count[i] = 0;
    }

    // Increment the corrosponding index in the count array
    for(i=0; i<size; i++){
        count[A[i]] = count[A[i]] + 1;
    }

    i = 0;  // Counter for count array
    j = 0;  // Counter for given array

    while(i <= max){
        if(count[i] > 0){
            A[j] = i;
            count[i] = count[i] - 1;
            j++;
        }
        else{
            i++;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    int A[] = {56,23,53,13,64,34};
    int n = 6;
    displayArray(A,n);
    countSort(A,n);
    displayArray(A,n);
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: What output are you getting? I quickly ran it here and it seems to work fine.

Comment: The loop that initializes the count array is using `size+1` when it should be using `max+1`.

Comment: Now I added an Image and a desired output too

Comment: Error messages should generally be posted as text, not as an image, unless you have a special reason to post them as an image. You may want to read this: [Why not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12149471)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This loop

```
// Initialize the count array elements to zero
for(i=0; i < size+1; i++){
    count[i] = 0;
}
```

does not set all elements of the dynamically allocated array to zeroes.

It seems you mean

```
// Initialize the count array elements to zero
for(i=0; i < max+1; i++){
    count[i] = 0;
}
```

Or if to include the header `<string.h>` then you can write

```
memset( count, 0, ( max + 1 ) * sizeof( int ) );
```

Or you could initially allocate and initialize the array with zeroes using standard function `calloc` instead of `malloc`.

Pay attention to that the code will not work if the array contains negative  numbers.

Comment: thanks I used max+1 instead of size +1 and it worked